# How would you say "all of that sitting around"?

Tags: word-choice, translation

How would you say to someone when they ask why you don't want to do something and the reason is "all of that sitting around and waiting"

Answer (score 5):

“All of that sitting around and waiting” is a little idiomatic/colloquial.

I would go with -- 
“Mi ne volas fari tion pro…”:

- *la atendado/sidado/enuiĝo*.
- *ke ĝi estas enuiga*.
- *ke mi ne volas sidi kaj atendi la tutan nokton*.

Answer (score 2):

Something like *la tuto de tia sidado kaj atendado*.

> "Via patro ŝatis spekti birdojn. Ĉu vi ankaŭ faras tion?"
>
> "Ne, neniam."
>
> "Kial ne?"
>
> "Pro la sidado kaj atendado, la tuto. Tiaĵoj enuigas min."

Answer (score 2):

> **A: Kial vi ne volas fari tion?**
>
> **B: Tro da sidado kaj atendado.**
>
> *A: Why don't you want to do that?*
>
> *B: Too much sitting and waiting.*